# Which method of managing an array of tiles is better?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So in this game I'm programming the "board" is an Array of tiles. I have to get which type of tile is at certain positions and move them around. Not every position that could have a tile has a tile.

I see two ways of doing this.

**1)** Have a 2D Array of tiles. The dimensions of the board in tiles would be equal to the dimensions of the Array. Places where there is no tile would be represented by `null`. These would be organized so that `myArray[1][1]` would refer to the tile at (1, 1).

Pros: Easy to find a tile at a specific coordinate

Cons: Seems bulky, many of the Tiles in the array will be null.

**2)** Have a regular unordered ArrayList of tiles. Since tiles have an x and a y component, I do not need to sort this.

Pros: Lightweight, takes less memory

Cons: When I need to find a tile at a specific coordinate I will need to use a for loop and search through every tile

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The question in my mind is: is it better to use a concrete array or a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array), and the solution (again in my mind) is "it depends". If your universe is potentially very large, then definitely use the sparse array, else you'll be wasting resources on cells that have no current relevance. If on the other hand the universe will be well limited in size, then the convenience of a concrete array (or some type of collection) will come to the fore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hashmap. Where keep the coordinate as key. And tile value at value position.
Ex pos(2,3)->2.3 so on .. 
This way search and memory both can be optimized.